# cart/checkout blank in Magento 2.2.8

Tags: magento2, cart, error

**Issue**
After upgrading to Magento 2.2.8. Cart and checkout page showing blank after adding Product to cart

**Server Error**

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFinalProduct() on null in /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.co.uk/staging.mywebsite.co.uk/vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php:129\nStack trace:\n#0

/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.co.uk/staging.mywebsite.co.uk/app/code/MGS/Mpanel/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php(81): Magento\\Checkout\\CustomerData\\DefaultItem->getProductForThumbnail()\n#1

/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.co.uk/staging.mywebsite.co.uk/vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/AbstractItem.php(31): MGS\\Mpanel\\CustomerData\\DefaultItem->doGetItemData()\n#2

/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.co.uk/staging.mywebsite.co.uk/vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/ItemPool.php(63): Magento\\Checkout\\CustomerData\\AbstractItem->getItemData(Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Item\\Interceptor))\n#3

/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.co.uk/staging.mywebsite.co.uk/vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/Cart.php(166): Magento\\C...\n', referer: https://staging.mywebsite.co.uk/baseball-cap.html
```

**defaultitem.php**

```
 <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace MGS\Mpanel\CustomerData;

    /**
     * Default item
     */
    class DefaultItem extends \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image
         */
        protected $imageHelper;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data
         */
        protected $msrpHelper;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
         */
        protected $urlBuilder;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool
         */
        protected $configurationPool;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data
         */
        protected $checkoutHelper;

        /**
         * @var \MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Data
         */
        protected $panelHelper;

        /**
         * @var \MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Data
         */
        protected $panelImageHelper;

        /**
         * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper
         * @param \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data $msrpHelper
         * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
         * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool $configurationPool
         * @param \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $checkoutHelper
         * @codeCoverageIgnore
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
            \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data $msrpHelper,
            \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
            \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool $configurationPool,
            \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $checkoutHelper,
            \MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Data $panelHelper,
            \MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Image $panelImageHelper
        ) {
            $this->configurationPool = $configurationPool;
            $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
            $this->msrpHelper = $msrpHelper;
            $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
            $this->checkoutHelper = $checkoutHelper;
            $this->panelHelper = $panelHelper;
            $this->panelImageHelper = $panelImageHelper;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        protected function doGetItemData()
        {
            $imageSize = $this->panelHelper->getImageMinSize();
            $imageHelper = $this->panelImageHelper->init($this->getProductForThumbnail(), 'mini_cart_product_thumbnail');
            return [
                'options' => $this->getOptionList(),
                'qty' => $this->item->getQty() * 1,
                'item_id' => $this->item->getId(),
                'configure_url' => $this->getConfigureUrl(),
                'is_visible_in_site_visibility' => $this->item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility(),
                'product_name' => $this->item->getProduct()->getName(),
                'product_sku' => $this->item->getProduct()->getSku(),
                'product_url' => $this->getProductUrl(),
                'product_has_url' => $this->hasProductUrl(),
                'product_price' => $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($this->item->getCalculationPrice()),
                'product_price_value' => $this->item->getCalculationPrice(),
                'product_image' => [
                    'src' => $imageHelper->getUrl(),
                    'alt' => $imageHelper->getLabel(),
                    'width' => $imageSize['width'],
                    'height' => $imageSize['height'],
                ],
                'canApplyMsrp' => $this->msrpHelper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($this->item->getProduct())
                    && $this->msrpHelper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($this->item->getProduct()),
            ];
        }
    }
```

**Line 81**

```
$imageHelper = $this->panelImageHelper->init($this->getProductForThumbnail(), 'mini_cart_product_thumbnail');
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<type name="MGS\Mpanel\Model\Mpanel">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="resource" xsi:type="object">MGS\Mpanel\Model\ResourceModel\Mpanel</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<preference for="Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data" type="MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Swatches\Data" />
<preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem" type="MGS\Mpanel\CustomerData\DefaultItem" />
<preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\CustomerData\ConfigurableItem" type="MGS\Mpanel\CustomerData\DefaultItem" />
<preference for="Magento\GroupedProduct\CustomerData\GroupedItem" type="MGS\Mpanel\CustomerData\DefaultItem" />
<preference for="Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist" type="MGS\Mpanel\CustomerData\Wishlist" />

<preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page" type="MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page" />

<preference for="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" type="MGS\Mpanel\Block\Cms\Block" />
<preference for="Magento\Cms\Block\Page" type="MGS\Mpanel\Block\Cms\Page" />

<preference for="Magento\User\Block\User\Edit" type="MGS\Mpanel\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit" />

<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder" type="MGS\Mpanel\Block\Product\ImageBuilder" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View" type="MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Product\View" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View" type="MGS\Mpanel\Controller\Category\View" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category" type="MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category" />
```

*Can anyone please suggest a solution?*

Comment: You have a custom module installed MGS/Mpanel. Please try to disable it and test if it's working. If yes it come from the module so paste your code from : app/code/MGS/Mpanel/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php(81)
And the di.xml of this module.

Comment: Hi @Vinz added those for you, thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the contents of app/code/MGS/Mpanel/etc/di.xml to the following

```
<type name="MGS\Mpanel\Model\Mpanel">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="resource" xsi:type="object">MGS\Mpanel\Model\ResourceModel\Mpanel</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>


<preference for="Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data" type="MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Swatches\Data" />
<!--<preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem" type="MGS\Mpanel\CustomerData\DefaultItem" />-->
<preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\CustomerData\ConfigurableItem" type="MGS\Mpanel\CustomerData\DefaultItem" />
<preference for="Magento\GroupedProduct\CustomerData\GroupedItem" type="MGS\Mpanel\CustomerData\DefaultItem" />
<preference for="Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist" type="MGS\Mpanel\CustomerData\Wishlist" />

<preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page" type="MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page" />

<preference for="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" type="MGS\Mpanel\Block\Cms\Block" />
<preference for="Magento\Cms\Block\Page" type="MGS\Mpanel\Block\Cms\Page" />

<preference for="Magento\User\Block\User\Edit" type="MGS\Mpanel\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit" />

<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder" type="MGS\Mpanel\Block\Product\ImageBuilder" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View" type="MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Product\View" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View" type="MGS\Mpanel\Controller\Category\View" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category" type="MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category" />
```